# Smartsheet API ---- how to upload an Image to a cell on a sheet, then send it to back-end (to AWS S3, get URL, for MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, amazon-s3, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

**Problem:**

- Smartsheet allows users to add images to a cell, by right-clicking on a cell then selecting 'Upload Image'
- We are trying to see how that image could then be sent to our back-end, so that the image is stored in AWS S3, where we get the image URL, so that in turn we can store it in our database, MongoDB

**What has been tried so far:**

- The entire process described on previous paragraph (i.e. send image to S3 and MongoDB) we've been able to do from a mobile app we developed (in Flutter), the difference is now we are trying to start the image upload from Smartsheet, uploading the image from the cell
- Using the Smartsheet API we've been able to both 'read' and 'write' to our back-end (NodeJS, MongoDB). We have yet to figure out the issue with "uploading Images from the Smartsheet API", is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the [Cell Images](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#cell-images) section of the Smartsheet API docs contains the info you're looking for. In particular, you'll probably find the information you're looking for in one or both of the following sections:

- [Add Image to Cell](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#add-image-to-cell) - describes how to use the API to add an image to a cell of a sheet.
- [Download Cell Image](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#download-cell-image) - describes how to use the API to retrieve an image that's stored in the cell of a sheet. `

Comment: Hi Kim, 
I hope not to be bothering.  Great, the answer to me seems perfect, so I tried to contact you on LinkedIn. Great if you could review. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jose - thanks for reaching out. I just responded to your LinkedIn message.

Comment: Thanks Kim. I just responded on LinkedIn.